# Mixed model not finding significant differences but post-hoc comparison test is

Tags: mixed-model, post-hoc, paired-comparisons, lme4-nlme, tukey-hsd-test

I am running a mixed model on something akin to this data:

```
df<-data.frame(stage=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c"),
nematode=c("fn","fn","bn","bn","fn","fn","bn","bn","fn","fn","bn","bn"),
id2=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
value=c(1,0,0,2,3,1,1,2,0,0,0,2))
```

And fit this mixed model:

```
stage.id <- function(x) round(summary(glmer(value ~ stage + (1 | id2),family="poisson", data = x))$coefficients[2, c(1, 2, 4)], 3)
models.id0  <- ddply(df, .( nematode), stage.id)
```

This revealed (for my raw data anyway) that some of the nematodes differed among stages.  So, let's assume that in the above example, bn p=0.014 and fn p=0.3.

I ran post-hoc (Tukey) comparison tests to see which of the stages were different.

```
bn<-subset(df,nematode=="bn")
bn.mod<-glmer(value ~ stage + (1 | id2),  family="poisson", data = bn)
bn.tuk<-glht(bn.mod,mcp(stage="Tukey"))
summary(bn.tuk)
tuk.cld <- cld(bn.tuk)   # letter-based display
opar <- par(mai=c(1,1,1.5,1))
plot(tuk.cld)
par(opar)
```

We had significant differences and it worked nicely as far as I can tell.  However, when I checked to make sure that the Tukey test wouldn't find any significant differences between fn, it detected several significant differences between the stages at p<0.001.  Why the discrepancy?

Comment: What is `tree2`? I don't see it defined

Comment: Sorry, I tried to reformat the code to match my sample data frame.  tree2=df

Comment: I need data  and not akin